# How to get Current location through google API?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, location

Can I get current location through Google API without enable GPS in android phone of api level on 19+.

Comment: man but i need without enable of gps or location is it possible?

Comment: why people are giving -ve vote please clarify man?

Comment: not possible without turning Location On

Comment: -ve votes because it looks like you dont make much effort to find answer to ur question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the location is disabled in the device settings, it means that the user does not want the apps to know his location, and the OS **should**, **have to** and **DOES** respect his choice. So there is no way, and should be no way to get location, at least from google API.

However, you can use internet and IP geolocation to determine approximate location of the user.

For example this service: http://ip-api.com/
usage: calling this URL: http://ip-api.com/json
will return all basic information about caller's IP
Calling this: http://ip-api.com/json/208.80.152.201
will return basic information about a specified IP.

Comment: Thank you @Vlad Matvienko. for gave me some information.

Comment: yeah i used priviously.